# Python math domain error

Tags: python, math, quadratic, sqrt

I am making a program that solves the quadratic equation and prints the roots. Before I get to the main program, I am just trying to make the square root work. The error I am getting says "math domain error". If someone could give me some help as to why it is not working that would be great.

```
import math

    a = int(sys.argv[1])
    b = int(sys.argv[2])
    c = int(sys.argv[3])
    x1 = int
    x2 = int
    #  variables into solving equation and assign answers
    print(math.sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))
```

Comment: Probably you input values that evaulate to negative number. `math.sqrt` won't give you complex numbers.

Comment: The lines `x1 = int` and `x2 = int` don't do anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

It's known that`sqrt` gives that error when you try to use it with a negative number.

The result probably is a complex number, and as stated in the comments by 098799, *"math.sqrt won't give you complex numbers"*.

Instead of using:

```
import math
print(math.sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))
```

Try using:

```
import cmath
print(cmath.sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))
```

It works with [cmath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html), because it provides access to mathematical functions for complex numbers.

Comment: so what does cmath mean?

Comment: Complex mathematics, in which sqrt (-1) == i (or j as some say). But given the fact you're just learning quadratic equations I don't think you'll need to learn complex numbers now. You just should test that b**2 - 4*a*c >= 0. If it's > 0, you'll find 2 solutions, if it's == 0 you'll find one solution. And indeed x1 = int and x2 = int won't get you anywhere.